# RegExp for specific string containing any number

Tags: javascript, regex, string

This is probably a super simple RegExp, but I'm really bad and can only get so far. So can some one help please :)

I want to test for a specific string that contains a number. So for example, `string/[0-9]/[*]`. So some examples:

```
/string/12 = true  
/string/0/ = true  
/string/123/anything = true  

/string123 = false  
/string/123abc = false
```

So far, all I have got to it:

```
RegExp('/string/[0-9]').test('/string/123')
```

But this doesn't work for all the scenarios above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to ensure that after `/string/`, there are one or more digits, followed by either `/` or the end of the string:

```js
const validate = str => console.log(/^\/string\/\d+(?:\/|$)/.test(str));

[
  '/string/12',
  '/string/0/',
  '/string/123/anything',

  '/string123',
  '/string/123abc',
].forEach(validate);
```

Your original regex only checked that there was a *single* digit after the `/`.

Comment: How would I use this in a `match()` expression to extract the number in the string? So for `/string/123/anything`, How would I use `match()` to retrieve the `123`?

Comment: Surround the digits in a group, and then continually use `exec` until there are no more matches, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression . Unfortunately there's no simple built-in way to extract groups like that